# Big O notation on this fibonacci number generator (specifically in MATLAB)

Tags: c++, matlab, recursion, big-o, fibonacci

This is a question from one of my current assignments and it's just killing me right now. I'm aware a similar question was asked a while back but this one is slightly different and I can't get it for the life of me.

Assuming we are using the below function to calculate Fibonacci numbers:

```
 function f = fibnum(n) 
    % FIBNUM Fibonacci number. 
    % FIBNUM(n) generates the nth Fibonacci number. 
    if n <= 1 
        f = 1; 
    else 
        f = fibnum(n-1)+fibnum(n-2); 
    end
```

How many arithmetic, logical, and assignment operations do we need to calculate the nth Fibonacci number, i.e. fibnum(n)? (assume each <= , = , + , -  is such an operation).  Do not include any operation related to returning from the function.  That is, you can ignore any effect of the line

```
 function f = fibnum(n)
```

Note fibnum(0) == 1 here.

Comment: Draw the sucker out. You'll see a binary tree of sorts.

Comment: Although I haven't learned binary trees yet in my class which is strange, I'm assuming there must be another way to do this. Although I will certainly look into those.

Comment: Don't worry about whether you know binary trees. Start drawing a diagram of how your function calls itself. Fibnum(5) for example, calls fibnum(4) and fibnum(3). Each of those function calls makes more function calls, and so on. See the picture in this answer for an idea of what you're doing. http://math.stackexchange.com/a/178401

Comment: I've drawn out the tree and I know what it means but I can't seem to translate that into a function of the nth fib number calculating the number of operations